# Linq - conditional Contains()

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, contains

I have the following method for filtering shops by the criteria specified in parameters:

```
public int[] GetShopIds(IEnumerable<Guid> OrderCreaatorIds, IEnumerable<Guid> OrderItemCategoryIds, int StatusId)
    {
        var query = from s in _db.Shops
                    join o in _db.Orders on s.Id equals o.ShopId
                    join oi in _db.OrderItems on o.Id equals oi.OrderId
                    where
                    OrderCreaatorIds.Contains(o.CreatorId)
                    && OrderItemCategoryIds.Contains(oi.CategoryId)
                    && (int)o.StatusId == StatusId
                    select s.Id;

        return query.ToArray();
    }
```

The thing is: `OrderCreaatorIds`, `OrderItemCategoryIds` can be `null` and `StatusId` can be `0`. In that case I do not want to have those where clauses, e.g. if `OrderCreaatorIds` is `null` then the query should work as follows:

```
public int[] GetShopIds(IEnumerable<Guid> OrderCreaatorIds, IEnumerable<Guid> OrderItemCategoryIds, int StatusId)
    {
        var query = from s in _db.Shops
                    join o in _db.Orders on s.Id equals o.ShopId
                    join oi in _db.OrderItems on o.Id equals oi.OrderId
                    where
                    OrderItemCategoryIds.Contains(oi.CategoryId)
                    && (int)o.StatusId == StatusId
                    select s.Id;

        return query.ToArray();
    }
```

etc.

Unfortunately `where OrderCreaatorIds != null && OrderCreaatorIds.Contains(o.CreatorId)` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int[] GetShopIds(IEnumerable<Guid> OrderCreaatorIds, IEnumerable<Guid> OrderItemCategoryIds, int StatusId)
{
    var query = from s in _db.Shops
        join o in _db.Orders on s.Id equals o.ShopId
        join oi in _db.OrderItems on o.Id equals oi.OrderId
        select new { s = s, o = o, oi = oi };

    if (null != OrderCreaatorIds)
        query = query.Where(x_ => OrderCreaatorIds.Contains(x_.o.CreatorId));

    if (null != OrderItemCategoryIds)
        query = query.Where(x_ => OrderItemCategoryIds.Contains(x_.oi.CategoryId));

    if (0 < StatusId)
        query = query.Where(x_ => (int)x_.o.StatusId == StatusId);

    return query.select(x_ => x_.s.Id).ToArray();
}
```

Maybe you will have to add some casting to IQueryable<> to make it compilable. I did not check it in compiler.

Comment: I know its years later but don't use conditional "Yoda" checking but instead use unit tests/integration tests to catch logical errors like accidental assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```
var query = from s in _db.Shops
    join o in _db.Orders on s.Id equals o.ShopId
    join oi in _db.OrderItems on o.Id equals oi.OrderId
    where
    (OrderCreaatorIds==null || OrderCreaatorIds.Contains(o.CreatorId))
    && 
    (OrderItemCategoryIds==null || OrderItemCategoryIds.Contains(oi.CategoryId))
    &&
    (StatusId==0 || (int)o.StatusId == StatusId)
    select s.Id;
```

As you can see for each part of the where clause I have changed it from your simple predicate to an or check of two predicates. So now you have three things that are formed like `A || B`. Due to the way or logic works if A is true then B will be ignored. So in this case if `OrderItemCategoryIds` is `null` then it won't do the `OrderItemCategoryIds.Contains` check.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare the dynamic parts of the query in variables outside the query, and then use the variables inside like this:

```
public int[] GetShopIds(IEnumerable<Guid> OrderCreaatorIds, IEnumerable<Guid> OrderItemCategoryIds, int StatusId)
{
    var orders = _db.Orders.AsQueryable();
    if (StatusId != 0)
        orders = orders.Where(o => o.StatusId == StatusId);
    if (OrderCreaatorIds != null)
        orders = orders.Where(o => OrderCreaatorIds.Contains(o.CreatorId));

    var orderItems = _db.OrderItems;
    if (OrderItemCategoryIds != null)
        orderItems = orderItems.Where(oi => OrderItemCategoryIds.Contains(oi.CategoryId));

    var query = from s in _db.Shops
                join o in orders on s.Id equals o.ShopId
                join oi in orderItems on o.Id equals oi.OrderId
                select s.Id;

    return query.ToArray();
}
```